# Print Keys of 2 Separate Dictionaries Simultaneously

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries both containing string values. One contains observed electrical defects of a utility pole and the other contains observed structural defects, specific to different crews. I want to print all these dictionary keys simultaneously and adjacent to each other. This is the only way I really know how to reference dictionary keys:

```
With Sheets("Results")
    For Each Item In electricalNotes
       .Range("G" & iResults).Value = Item
       .Range("H" & iResults).Value = electricalNotes(Item)
       iResults = iResults + 1
    Next
End With
electricalNotes.RemoveAll
```

The problem is that my code to print the item and value for my structuralNotes dictionary is the same and must use the same incrementer iResults because the code has to recognize that these observations are paired with the respective crew. But I have to reference them separately since I only know how to do the "For Each" reference command. Since they are being referenced separately, they each have their own iResults incrementer, meaning it continues incrementing after it finishes with one dictionary, printing the structural defects (further left column with text) under the finished printing electrical defects (further right column with text). See the picture below in the link for help visualizing:
[Dictionary Help Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opj4L.png).

So if anyone knows how to fix this specific problem or knows a better way to reference and subsequently print the items stored in two dictionaries simultaneously the help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems like you could use a [nested loop](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-for-loop/). While the completeness is appreciated in your post, there's quite a bit of information here that's unnecessary to help you out. Please check out the help center's information on creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)(minimal, complete, verifiable example)

Comment: How can you correlate the keys of each dictionary to each crew? Do both dictionaries have the same number of keys for each crew? If not, how do you determine that the keys in both belong to the same crew?

Comment: @wahwahwah A form of nested loop is the direction I went in. I also want to thank you for the link to posting an MCVE, I am very much a beginner and it was helpful for creating questions and examples in the future.

Comment: @paulbica Your questions actually helped steer me in the right direction. I had both dictionaries running in the same nested loop with an If statement making sure that the key entry existed in case one dictionary had more entries than the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little hard for me to understand your structure, but, assuming a one-to-one correlation between the keys in `electricalNotes` and the keys in `structuralNotes`, all you have to do is read the keys into two separate variant arrays, then iterate through the arrays using a counter.  Something like:

```
v1 = d1.Keys
v2 = d2.Keys

ReDim v3(1 To d1.Count, 1 To 4) 'or write directly to the worksheet

Dim I As Long

For I = 0 To d1.Count - 1
    v3(I + 1, 1) = v1(I)
    v3(I + 1, 2) = d1(v1(I))
    v3(I + 1, 3) = v2(I)
    v3(I + 1, 4) = d2(v2(I))
Next I
```

- `v1=d1.keys` will create a zero-based one-dimensional array of the keys in the dictionary.
- I chose to write the results into a vba array (`v3`), but you could write directly to the worksheet.  The latter would be much slower.  You can write `v3` to the worksheet in a single step after populating it.
- Note that `v3` is a one-based two-dimensional array to correspond to the worksheet, so you have to adjust the index `I` depending on which array you are referencing.  I did it that way so, if you wanted, you could `Dim v3` as a zero based array, and use v(0,1-4) for column headers.

Comment: Using your help and someone else's here in the office with me I was able to construct something very similar to your code that works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @MattGaydon Glad to help. Thanks for the feedback.